# Maven spark dependency error: object spark is not a member of package org.apache

Tags: scala, maven, intellij-idea, apache-spark

I am trying to import Spark to my scala project using maven in IntelliJ. The dependency is

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

but I am getting this error

```
Error:(4, 19) object spark is not a member of package org.apache
import org.apache.spark.Partitioner
                  ^
```

Comment: have you tried re-importing the dependencies of your pom file?

Comment: Try clearing the caches of Intellij